# Using powershell can a non-admin user, change password of a user of remote machine which has windows operating system if existing password is known?

Tags: windows, powershell, password, user-accounts

I have 2 machines. From machine A i log in as a user without admin privileges. I need to change the password of another user say BUser who is administrator in machine B by providing the existing old password of BUser. Can this be done via powershell script. I have tried this by logging in as an Administrator and changing the password where in old password was not necessary. But can a non-admin user change the password if he knows the existing password of the user present in MachineB.

The machines which i am referring here are all in workgroup and not in domain.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, there is a Windows API to change a password for any user as long as you know the old password, you don't have to be an admin. I think you need to be local on the machine, so you need to open a remote session in PowerShell. I don't have access to my scripts right now, but I sure there is already an answer on this site or Superuser.com

Comment: You seem to have two accounts you have used regarding this question.  https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @JayashreeShetty Hi, please try to edit with the same account, you can merge with your account Jaya too, you can use the contact us link to ask to do so.

Comment: You need to have admin rights on Machine B to change the password of Administrator